# self-defined type cast to string in VHDL

Tags: casting, vhdl

I created a VHDL package with a new type as you can see below:

```
package useOfLength is

    type length1 is range -(2**31-1) to 2**31-1
    units
        um;
        mm = 1000 um;
        cm = 10 mm;
        m = 100 cm;
        inch = 25400 um;
        yard = 914400 um;
        foot = 304800 um;
    end units;

end;
```

in my testbench I am trying to "report" the variable "output" of a signal of type length1:

```
report "The result is " & to_string(output);
```

Modelsim gives me the following error message:

> ** Error: G:/OneDrive - Office/SS2018/DRS/exercise6/1106ex03/ex03_tb.vhd(49): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "to_string".

I tried a lot (cast to integer and then to string) and also other ways, but nothing is working. I also found casts on the internet, but only for already given types, not for self-defined types.
I am also new to VHDL and maybe this is a stupid question...

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008, 5.2.6 Predefined operations on scalar types "Given a type declaration that declares a scalar type T, the following operations are implicitly declared immediately following the type declaration (except for the TO_STRING operations in package STANDARD, which are implicitly declared at the end of the package declaration):...`function TO_STRING (VALUE: T) return STRING;`" Use -2008 mode in Modelsim. (And negative lengths appear a bit odd.)

Comment: Casting isn't an accurate term here. Type conversion is only allowed between closely related types and your scalar type and the composite type string are not closely related (9.3.6 Type conversion). TO_STRING is a function when called returns a string representation. For a physical type that's an integer value followed by a space and the primary unit name. (Type TIME uses the resolution unit name, see 5.7 String representations.)

Comment: ahh okay thanks! I also solved it with this: length1'image(output);       which is compilable and also working fine =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, I found out, that a physical type is the same as an integer...

so to convert it to a string is working like this:

```
length1'image(output);
```

Comment: ... but you probably want to write a custom function where you can specify the display unit, [like write function in the textio package has for input type time](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/218051/vhdl-how-to-change-the-resolution-of-time-printed-using-now-in-vhdl-to-file-o).

Comment: A GPL licensed example of the textio write procedure described by @JHBonarius can be found in https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/blob/master/libraries/std/textio_body.vhdl at line 246. It could easily be modified for another physical type or be used as a reference to 'teach' you how to write your own originally authored procedure.